# Integral inequality involving Gaussian

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

I am reading a paper where there is the following inequality:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-\frac{(y-\alpha)^2}{2}}-e^{-\frac{{y^2}}{2}}\right|dy\leq e^\frac{\alpha^2}{2}-1$$ where $\alpha > 0$. Do you have any idea on how to prove it?

Comment: There is obviously a misprint. This being corrected, and using Schwarz inequality I found only the majorization $\sqrt{2\pi}(e^{\alpha^2}-1)^{1/2}.$

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I think  that your inequality $I\leq e^{\alpha^2}-1$ is not correct when $\alpha$ is very small. To see this I write $\alpha=2\beta$, leading to $$I\sqrt{2\pi}=\int_R \left|e^{-\frac{(x-\beta)^2}{2}}-e^{-\frac{(x+\beta)^2}{2}}\right|dx=e^{-\beta^2/2}\int_R e^{-x^2/2}\left|e^{\beta x}-e^{-\beta x}\right|dx=2e^{-\beta^2/2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\left(e^{\beta x}-e^{-\beta x}\right)dx=2\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-(x-\beta)^2/2}-e^{-(x+\beta)^2/2}\right)dx=2\int_{-\beta}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}dt-2\int_{\beta}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}dt=2\int_{-\beta}^{\beta}e^{-t^2/2}dt\sim_{\beta\to 0} 4\beta$$ However the searched majorization $$\sqrt{2\pi}(e^{4\beta^2}-1)\sim_{\beta\to 0} \sqrt{2\pi}\times 4\beta^2$$ is much smaller.